# Why boost::property_tree::read_xml throws reading valid Office Open XML?

Tags: c++, xml, excel, exception, boost

I'm using Boost 1.62.0 and trying to parse an Excel .xlsx file which according to [the ISO standard](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c061750_ISO_IEC_29500-1_2012.zip) contains various XML files. It reads [Content_Types].xml file just fine. But for the second (workbook.xml.rels) and third (workbook.xml) files that I'm trying to read it throws an exception like this:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/property_tree/detail/xml_parser_read_rapidxml.hpp(138): Throw in function void boost::property_tree::xml_parser::read_xml_internal(std::basic_istream<typename Ptree::key_type::value_type> &, Ptree &, int, const std::string &) [Ptree = boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >]
Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::property_tree::xml_parser::xml_parser_error> >
std::exception::what: ../tmp/UX0s9R9kBpSxFB40s9OTzTD9/xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels(1): expected <
```

Here is the /xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels (it's minified by default):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Id="rId8" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Target="worksheets/sheet8.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId13" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Target="worksheets/sheet13.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId18" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/theme" Target="theme/theme1.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId3" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Target="worksheets/sheet3.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId7" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Target="worksheets/sheet7.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId12" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Target="worksheets/sheet12.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId17" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Target="worksheets/sheet17.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Target="worksheets/sheet2.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId16" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Target="worksheets/sheet16.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId20" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/sharedStrings" Target="sharedStrings.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Target="worksheets/sheet1.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId6" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Target="worksheets/sheet6.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId11" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Target="worksheets/sheet11.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId5" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Target="worksheets/sheet5.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId15" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Target="worksheets/sheet15.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId10" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Target="worksheets/sheet10.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId19" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/styles" Target="styles.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId4" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Target="worksheets/sheet4.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId9" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Target="worksheets/sheet9.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId14" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Target="worksheets/sheet14.xml"/></Relationships>
```

And /xl/workbook.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<workbook xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"><fileVersion appName="xl" lastEdited="5" lowestEdited="5" rupBuild="9302"/><workbookPr defaultThemeVersion="124226"/><bookViews><workbookView xWindow="360" yWindow="420" windowWidth="24675" windowHeight="11805" firstSheet="3" activeTab="16"/></bookViews><sheets><sheet name="Sheet1" sheetId="1" r:id="rId1"/><sheet name="Sheet2" sheetId="2" r:id="rId2"/><sheet name="Sheet3" sheetId="3" r:id="rId3"/><sheet name="Sheet4" sheetId="4" r:id="rId4"/><sheet name="Sheet5" sheetId="5" r:id="rId5"/><sheet name="Sheet6" sheetId="6" r:id="rId6"/><sheet name="Sheet7" sheetId="7" r:id="rId7"/><sheet name="Sheet8" sheetId="8" r:id="rId8"/><sheet name="Sheet9" sheetId="9" r:id="rId9"/><sheet name="Sheet10" sheetId="10" r:id="rId10"/><sheet name="Sheet11" sheetId="11" r:id="rId11"/><sheet name="Sheet12" sheetId="12" r:id="rId12"/><sheet name="Sheet13" sheetId="13" r:id="rId13"/><sheet name="Sheet14" sheetId="14" r:id="rId14"/><sheet name="Sheet15" sheetId="15" r:id="rId15"/><sheet name="Sheet16" sheetId="16" r:id="rId16"/><sheet name="Sheet17" sheetId="17" r:id="rId17"/></sheets><calcPr calcId="144525"/></workbook>
```

I have already verified the XML using various online XML validators and it passed all of them. Any idea why boost::property_tree::read_xml expects a '<' at the first line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the answer from [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/property_tree/parsers.html#property_tree.parsers.xml_parser):

> Unfortunately, there is no XML parser in Boost as of the time of this writing. The library therefore contains the fast and tiny RapidXML parser (currently in version 1.13) to provide XML parsing support. RapidXML does not fully support the XML standard; it is not capable of parsing DTDs and therefore cannot do full entity substitution.

So, it seems I have to use another XML parser.